# jQuery code - IE8 problem

Tags: jquery

I have this code that changes input fields name attribute value, works great in all major browsers except IE8, IE7 and IE6. For IE the name just stay `name="participant_name[{i}]"`, should be `name="participant_name[1]"`.

```
var i = 1;
var input_name = null;
$('.dubl input').each(function () {
   var new_input_name = $(this).attr('name').substring(0, $(this).attr('name').indexOf('['));
   if (input_name !== new_input_name) {
       input_name = new_input_name;
       i = 1;
   }
   $(this).attr('name', input_name + '[' + i + ']');
   i++;
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="participant_name[{i}]">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in fact changing the attribute `name` correctly in IE as well. However, I think the problem you may be experiencing is that when you submit the form, it isn't the updated field `name`.

IE doesn't take into account that `name` change and as such, when the form is sent, it is still using the same `name` as it was when it was created. To fix this, you can either re-add it to the DOM the form/element when you change the name attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/wbnhS/ you can test it there, the attribute does change or if you inspect the DOM in IE.

Comment: I'm bit confused, my script doesn't change the name attribute, but in the link you provided everything works fine. But I haven't understood how can I fix this. :(

Comment: @elvis How do you know yours isn't changing it as well? Where exactly are the unexpected results showing up?

Comment: Actually you made a point, possibly this isn't cause of my problem. I'm using dynamic form field with relcopy and validation plugin. I got following js error in IE - "'form' is null or not an object" in jquery.validate.js. Since I have multiple forms and some of the forms work without errors in IE, I noticed that forms which use attribute [{i}] for name don't work. So I assumed that the problem was there. Now I'm kind of stuck :(. Parhaps the problem is simply in validation plugin, the line on which it shows error looks like this - var meta = $.data(element.form, 'validator').settings.meta;

Comment: @elvis at this point its quite difficult for us to give you any more advice with the amount of code/information you've provided us. However, if this is purely an IE issue, the explanation I gave could very well be the reason it isn't working as intended.

Comment: Ok, but I didn't understood your fix :( Quote "To fix this, you can either re-add it to the DOM the form/element when you change the name attribute."

Comment: @elvis instead of changing the attribute of the name of the input, replace the whole input element with a new one or recreate the entire form again.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. I guess I need to learn more of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

use .replace!

here's a quick fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/H5fkq/

Answer (score 0):

If this is not the only place in your project where you need to do such replacements on the client, maybe it's worth looking at a templating library, e.g., [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/).